# Color Object Tracking in 3D space

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently working on color object tracking base on PCL, the expectation will be tracking X-Y-Z of object in 3D space.

Please help me an direction should I get start?

I have work with HSI in PCL , color base for recognize the color of Object.But no reliable and stable some time it disappear and appear again.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11062/color-object-tracking-in-3d-space/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is well and truly an open research problem; reading the [PCL tutorials](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/) could tell you what that library can do, but there's no cut-and-dried solution to this.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2015-04-05**:
Why not, actually? I mean, it's a pretty common task, isn't it? There could be some baked solution for finding instances of cloud A in cloud B, returning their poses... (sorry for exhuming this old thread)